# How open docker volume?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-volume

I don't know how to open postgresql database

I am using Ubuntu 18.04. My Dockerfile is based on ubuntu 18.04 too. On Host machine I have postgresql version 10.9. In docker-compose I use postgresql image version 10.9 too.  My docker store database as volume.

I store my database like:

```
volumes:
  - ./database:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Database seems to be saved correctly. **How open it?**

I tryied edit /etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf file. I changed:

```
data_directory = '/var/lib/postgresql/10/main'
```

to

```
data_directory = '/my_absolute_path/database'
```

then I restarted postgresql.

When I typed:

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
  Is the server running locally and accepting
  connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Structure of directories in

```
/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

and

```
/var/lib/postgresql/10/main
```

are the same, but in

```
/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

I see four additional files:

```
pg_hba.conf

pg_ident.conf 

postgresql.auto.conf 

postmaster.opts
```

When I delete these files I see the same error

Comment: Would it not be easier to expose a port on the Docker container and connect to postgres that way?

Comment: Thank You for comment. It would be, but it's safer to use volumes.

Comment: If you write a port definition in your compose file like this `- "127.0.0.1:<host_port>:<container_port>"` you can expose a port to local applications on the host only. Would this be suitable?

Comment: It's not suitable for me. I want be independent from container. Thank You for help :)

Comment: What is your ordinary non-Docker workflow?  Looking at the `/var/lib/postgresql` files at all is rather unusual in my experience.  (There are ways to share a non-Docker database on the same host that might match better, for example.)

Comment: I am not sure, Am I understand You correctly @DavidMaze  I am using Scrapy to crawl some sites then I am saving data in postgresql database.